# Mathematical object which does not form a category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

For a given object $A$, does there always exists category of $A$ ?
For example, given integer does not form category.
Because it does not have morphism.

Is there known results(criterion) whether given object forms a category or not ?

Comment: You cannot omit morphisms ("because it does not have morphism"). The question should be just your first sentence: "For a given object $A$, does there always exists category of $A$ ?" Answer: yes, see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is fundamentally confused about what it means to form a category.

It presupposes that you can point to an object, or a class of objects, and ask: does *that* form a category or not? An object, or a class of objects, in and of itself is not something that either forms or doesn't form a category. You need to supply more information.

To produce a well-formed question, you need to ask about class of objects, *together with* (i) a specification of a class of morphisms, (ii) a specification of a class of identity morphisms, and (iii) a putative composition operation on morphisms.

Once you have specified all three of these, *then* you can ask: is this a category?

In particular, it does not make sense to say that "a given integer does not form a category because it does not have morphism". You are free to define morphisms however you like in a category. So, for example, I could take a category which consists only of the number $7$ together with exactly one identity arrow $\mathrm{id}\colon 7 \to 7$ which composes as $\mathrm{id} \circ \mathrm{id} = \mathrm{id}$. This is a perfectly legitimate specification of a category.